# Taking an image with the camera on API 19 crashes, but it works on API 21 and newer

Tags: android

I have an app that lets you make a list, and for each item you can put in a name, price, description, image, etc.

I started writing the app with the minimum API level 21. I'm currently trying to bring it down to API 19 so that I can get some of the KitKat users.

The problem happens when a user on API 19 tries to take a picture using the app. When they push the "take picture" button the camera pulls up just fine, but when they take a picture and hit the checkmark to save the image the camera app crashes.

Here is the error code in the logs for the camera app. The main line I'm seeing is this:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{a517eda0 12685:com.android.camera/u0a32} (pid=12685, uid=10032) that is not exported from uid 10057
```

---

```
Process: com.android.camera, PID: 12685
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{a517eda0 12685:com.android.camera/u0a32} (pid=12685, uid=10032) that is not exported from uid 10057
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2848)
at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4415)
at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2207)
at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1425)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:906)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:669)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:645)
at com.android.camera.Camera.doAttach(Camera.java:1385)
at com.android.camera.Camera.onReviewDoneClicked(Camera.java:1362)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

And also, since I believe it is a permissions kind of thing, here is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="jeremy.com.wineofmine">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="jeremy.com.wineofmine.MainActivity"

        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="jeremy.com.wineofmine.AddActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:parentActivityName="jeremy.com.wineofmine.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="jeremy.com.wineofmine.DetailsActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:parentActivityName="jeremy.com.wineofmine.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="jeremy.com.wineofmine.EditActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:parentActivityName="jeremy.com.wineofmine.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="jeremy.com.wineofmine.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>

    <activity android:name="jeremy.com.wineofmine.ImageActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="jeremy.com.wineofmine.DetailsActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Does anyone know whats going on here? I'm at a loss. I believe I gave the app permission to access the files using those two permission lines in the manifest.

If any additional code would be helpful just let me know.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Adding the camera intent code (before I did not have the FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION line, but I added it due to CommonsWare's post. It did not fix the issue):

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePictureIntent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "jeremy.com.wineofmine.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);

                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assuming that you are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Camera

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the code for the camera intent to the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I had it backwards in the comment. The camera app is writing, and so you need to add `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`.

**UPDATE** ...and, since you're trying to support Android 4.4, you need to also do [this crap](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/31/granting-permissions-uri-intent-extra.html):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
}
else {
  ClipData clip=
    ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "whatevs", outputUri);

  i.setClipData(clip);
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
}
```

where:

- `i` is the `Intent`
- `outputUri` is the value you are using for `EXTRA_OUTPUT`

Comment: I just changed it to 'takePictureIntent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);' but it's doing the exact same error yet. :( Any other ideas?

Comment: @andrdoiddev: See update -- I was blanking on your Android 4.4 objective.

Comment: And that code goes before my other code in that method? Here is what I have right now for the dispatchTakePictureIntent: https://pastebin.com/6jJRxcgV  I'm not entirely sure I'm implementing it correctly. I looked over the link you gave and I believe I am?

Comment: @andrdoiddev: "And that code goes before my other code in that method?" -- you can't use that code until you have your `Uri`, so that has to go after the `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` call, as `photoUri` is `null` before then.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I should have caught that one. Here is the new method: https://pastebin.com/VPjNHm4Q But I hate to say it, with this code I am still receiving the same exact error.

Comment: @andrdoiddev: You have to call that code *before* calling `startActivityForResult()`. The idea is that you are configuring the `Intent`, then starting the activity. As it stands, you are starting the activity before completing configuring the `Intent`. When I said "after the `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` call, I was thinking *immediately* after the `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` call.

Comment: damn this save my life been trying many things. thank you @CommonsWare